# blazor - captcha issue System.Drawing.Common is not supported

Tags: blazor, recaptcha, captcha, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I all, I am new in blazor and I am trying to implement captcha without success, I tried different NuGet packages and I get the following error "System.Drawing.Common is not supported on this platform."(also added this NuGet package), I am using wasm .NET core 5.0 what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

"System.Drawing.Common" has a dependency to GDI+ and can not be used in Blazor-Wasm.
But as it is using GDI+ it is preferrable to not use it at all on server/web-applications. The plan in .net (mostly 6) is to (slowly) get rid of it and use other libraries like SkiaSharp or ImageSharp.

You shoud try to use another lib.

How do you want to create the captcha?
You could use Canvas to create it from scratch ([Canvas Lib](https://github.com/excubo-ag/Blazor.Canvas)) or use [recaptcha via JS-Interop](https://github.com/sample-by-jsakamoto/Blazor-UseGoogleReCAPTCHA) or [hcaptcha (JS-Interop)](https://github.com/Texnomic/hCaptcha)